# Prove that a given set $S$ is convex

Tags: geometry, convex-geometry, convex-hulls

> Prove that the given set $$S = \left\{(x_1, x_2, x_3) \in \mathbb{R}^3 \middle| 0 \le x_1 \le x_2 \le x_3 \le 6\right\}$$ is convex.

My proof:

Let $x,y \in S$ and let $t \in [0,1]$

To prove that $S$ is convex, it suffices to show that $$tx+(1-t)y \in S$$.

However, this is where I get stuck. How can I use the constraints  $0 \le x_1 \le x_2 \le x_3 \le 6$ to form my argument?

Comment: Use the fact that $x$ and $y$ both satisfy these constraints to show that $tx+(1-t)y$ also satisfy them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x=(x_1, x_2, x_3)$ and $y=(y_1, y_2, y_3)$ be two points in $S,$ and let $t\in [0, 1].$ Note that $x_1, y_2\ge 0$ and hence $tx_1+(1-t)y_1\ge 0.$ Since $x_1\le x_2$ and $y_1\le y_2$ we get $$tx_1+(1-t)y_1\le tx_2+(1-t)y_2.$$
Exactly the same argument also shows that $tx_2+(1-t)y_2\le tx_3+(1-t)y_3.$ Lastly, since $x_3, y_3\le 6$ we have $tx_3+(1-t)y_3\le 6.$ This shows that $tx+(1-t)y\in S.$

Answer (score 0):

Let $x=(x_1, x_2, x_3)$ and $y=(y_1, y_2, y_3)$. Since $t\geq 0$ and $(1-t)\geq 0$,
$$t\cdot 0\le t\cdot x_1\le t\cdot x_2\le t\cdot x_3\le t\cdot 6\tag{1}$$
$$(1-t)\cdot 0\le (1-t)\cdot y_1\le (1-t)\cdot y_2\le (1-t)\cdot y_3\le (1-t)\cdot 6\tag{2}$$
By adding equation $(1)$ and $(2)$, we have
$$t\cdot 0+(1-t)\cdot 0\le t\cdot x_1+(1-t)\cdot y_1\le t\cdot x_2+(1-t)\cdot y_2\le t\cdot x_3+(1-t)\cdot y_3\le t\cdot 6+(1-t)\cdot 6$$
Simplifying
$$0\le t\cdot x_1+(1-t)\cdot y_1\le t\cdot x_2+(1-t)\cdot y_2\le t\cdot x_3+(1-t)\cdot y_3\le 6$$
Then
$$tx + (1-t)y \in S, \quad t\in[0,1]$$
$S$ is convex.